# Borderless selection highlight effect in Flutter

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

Context: I'm rewriting my Android app with Flutter. On Android, there was this interesting touch feedback effect when setting clickable `View`'s `background` property to `?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`:

[image]

Note that the red border wasn't in the real UI, it's there just to show `View`'s borders. As you can see, the ink forms a circle that is [circumscribed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) around the rectangular view.

I would like the ink in my Flutter app to be also circumscribed around the view, i.e. **the selection area needs to be circular and to encompass the view.** I'm trying to achieve this by using `InkResponse` component, but the result looks miserable:

[image]

The body of the `Scaffold` used in the example:

```dart
body: Center(
  // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
  // in the middle of the parent.
  child: Material(
    color: Color(0xff008080),
    child: Center(
      child: InkResponse(
        onTap: () {
          /* ... */
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('BUTTON'),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If I make the `radius` property of the `InkResponse` big enough, it can go beyond the view's bounds, and if my view had static size, I could tweak the property to achieve the desired effect, but in my real app it's dynamic.

**Is it possible to do it without making a custom component?**

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? any way to allow the ripple effect go beyond the widget render box?

Answer (score 1):

For these purposes, I think [InkResponse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html) should be used:

```
Container(
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  child: InkResponse(radius: 110, onTap: () {}, child: Text("text")));
```

[Working Example](https://dartpad.dev/474047adcd4f08d1e4b500e1855a0ed4?null_safety=true)

[image: InkResponse effect example]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, its click is bound into the red area.

```
Center(
          // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
          // in the middle of the parent.
          child: Material(
            color: Color(0xff008080),
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  /* ... */
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('BUTTON'),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm interested specifically in having a circular highlighted area that fully encompasses the view. Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question.